# How to install libprotobuf?

Tags: linux, software-installation, libraries

By mistake i have deleted these libraries. I couldn't find a right way to reinstall it.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-c.so.0
```

To fix it, i tried to follow these instructions, https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md
but ended up with different version. Now while compiling my code it throws this error. How can i get my previous version back?

```
error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the two packages providing libprotobuf.so.8, libprotobuf-c.so.0

```
apt-get install --reinstall libprotobuf8 libprotobuf-c0
```

If Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libprotobuf8 libprotobuf-c0`

Comment: Great. This installed libprotobuf.so.8. But i am still seeing this error while compiling my code.. any idea how to fix this? /usr/bin/protoc-c: error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory make: *** [t/test.pb-c.c] Error 127

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```

should solve the problem.